# .load() To Load Multiple Content Individually

Tags: jquery, ajax

<strike>The following script will pull content from other pages into a specified `DIV` on the main page. I would, >however, like to enable it to load content to the nearest `DIV` from the link(s) in `.links`, multiple of them, each functioning individually. This meaning, link 1 to 3 in `.links` on top of the page loading into the first `DIV` nearest to it, and `.links` 4-6 doing the same but in a different area of the same page.</strike>

**Update** I am trying to get the first link in every .class li to load in `.class + div` initially. I am also trying to get each element to work individually so that a link wont affect all the divs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.links + div').load($('.links li a:first').attr('href'));
    $(document).on('click','.links li a:not(.noajax)',function(e)  {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $link = $(this),
            url = $link.attr('href');
        $link.closest('.links').next('div').fadeOut('fast').load('+ page +').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="links">
    <li><a href="one.php">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="two.php">Two</a></li>
</ul>
<div></div>


<ul class="links">
    <li><a href="Three.php">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="Four.php">Four</a></li>
</ul>
<div></div>
```

Comment: PS, I want to use this script on other pages as well, so it would be ideal for me to not have to edit/update it for new elements.

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: Could you please tell us what is this `nearest`. Is it a Class or ID

Comment: Here is what Im working with at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/WjXYB/

Comment: This isn't working properly on jsfiddle, but is fine on my website, I only need the script to allow the function to work individually.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML structure you're using is fixed, such has:

```
<ul class="links">
 ...
</ul>
<div></div>


<ul class="links">
 ...
</ul>
<div></div>
```

Then you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.links + div').load('login.php')
    $(document).on('click','.links li a:not(.noajax)',function()  {
        /* code */
        $(this).closest('.links').next('div').fadeOut('fast').load('' + page + '.php').fadeIn('slow');
        /* code */
    });
});
```

---

If the HTML structure isn't fixed, then something like this would work:

```
<ul class="links" data-load-target="div1">
 ...
</ul>
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="div1"></div>


<ul class="links" data-load-target="div2">
 ...
</ul>
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="div2"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.links + div').load('login.php')
    $(document).on('click','.links li a:not(.noajax)',function()  {
        /* code */
        var loadTarget = $(this).closest('.links').data('load-target');
        if (loadTarget)
            $('#' + loadTarget).fadeOut('fast').load('' + page + '.php').fadeIn('slow');
        /* code */
    });
});
```

---

Update:

HTML

```
<ul class="links">
  <li><a href="login.php">Login</a>
</ul>
<div></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.links + div').load('login.php')
    $(document).on('click','.links li a:not(.noajax)',function(e)  {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $link = $(this),
            url = $link.attr('href');
        $link.closest('.links').next('div').fadeOut('fast').load(url).fadeIn('slow');
        /* code */
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My structure is similar to your first example, fixed. Though, the update to the script isn't working.

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to select clicked href and load it's content to the nearest div?

Comment: This isn't working either. It removes the loaded login.php individually when any link is clicked within it's element, but thats as far as it goes. Doesn't load anything new.